# Convert pandas DataFrame into nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

How can I convert a simple pandas DataFrame into a nested dictionary, where the first column of the dataframe is the main key of the dict, while all subsequent columns represent the values? That is, all subsequent columns become a dict themselves.

```
dataframe
Key     title   source
Key1    Test1   ABC
Key2    Test2   ABC
Key3    Test2   DEF


Nested dictionary
{
    {'Key1': {'title': 'Test1', 'source': 'ABC'},
    {'Key2': {'title': 'Test2', 'source': 'ABC'},
    {'Key3': {'title': 'Test2', 'source': 'DEF'},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_dict`. `to_dict` returns dictionary while `to_json` returns string. If you need `str`, use `to_json`. If you need dictionary, use `to_dict`

```
df.set_index('Key').to_dict('index')

Out[222]:
{'Key1': {'title': 'Test1', 'source': 'ABC'},
 'Key2': {'title': 'Test2', 'source': 'ABC'},
 'Key3': {'title': 'Test2', 'source': 'DEF'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.to_json` ... here is your case:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['Test1', 'ABC'], ['Test2', 'ABC'], ['Test2', 'DEF']],
...                    index=['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3'],
...                    columns=['title', 'source'])

>>> df
      title source
Key1  Test1    ABC
Key2  Test2    ABC
Key3  Test2    DEF

>>> df.to_json(orient='index')
{"Key1":{"title":"Test1","source":"ABC"},
 "Key2":{"title":"Test2","source":"ABC"},
 "Key3":{"title":"Test2","source":"DEF"}}
```

**NOTE:**

The only difference between your `dataframe` and mine is that mine has `key` as **index** which can be set using `df.set_index('Key')`